# erlang an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression

Tags: erlang

i am a beginner of erlang.
this is my code:

```
-module(squsum).
-export([main/0]).

ssum(1) -> 1;
ssum(N) -> N*N + ssum(N-1).

main() ->
    {_,T} = io:fread("","~d"),
    io:fwrite("~p~n",[ssum(T)]).
```

why will it have such a problem?

```
** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
     in function  squsum:ssum/1 (squsum.erl, line 5)
     in call from squsum:main/0 (squsum.erl, line 9)
```

Answer (score 3):

T is a list containing the value, I guess it is the symmetric point of view of IO:fwrite. so simply use:

```
main() -> {ok,[T]} = io:fread("","~d"), io:fwrite("~p~n",[ssum(T)]).
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with erlang, but if it is at all possible for T to be negative, then your recursive function would never end.

Similarly, if T=0, the function would never end.

Answer (score 0):

This is really on comment on Pascal's answer: just to add that io:fread/2 returns a list of the terms specified in the format string --- even if the format string has just one term, it returns a list with one element.

The erlang documentation is quite good. io:fread/2 is at http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fread-2